# How to fix "expected `Error`, found `Infallible`" error when reading Vec<u8> from an sqlite row?

Tags: sqlite, rust

For this code:

```rust
pub fn read_vecu8(row: &sqlite::Row, col: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    row.read::<Vec<u8>, _>(col).into()
}
```

I am getting this very simple error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<Vec<u8> as TryFrom<&Value>>::Error == Error`
   --> src/lib.rs:47:22
    |
47  |     row.read::<Vec<u8>, _>(col).into()
    |                         ^ expected `Error`, found `Infallible`
```

Note it's finding `Infallible`. When I switch this code to mirror this I get the same error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<Vec<u8> as TryFrom<&Value>>::Error == Error`
   --> src/lib.rs:47:22
    |
47  |     row.read::<Vec<u8>, !>(col).into()
    |                         ^ expected `Error`, found `Infallible`
```

How can I make this error go away? What does it want for this? row.read is from sqlite crate: https://docs.rs/sqlite/latest/sqlite/struct.Row.html#method.read

Comment: Please show us the code that's giving the error, not just the single line.

Comment: @V0ldek It's literally just the single line wrapped in a fn... `pub fn read_vecu8( row: &sqlite::Row, col: &str ) -> Vec<u8> { single line }`

Comment: "I'm not calling .into()" so the code is _not_ just that single line, because that line contains `.into()`...

Comment: I'm not sure why moderators deleted my response to @V0ldek showing why I was right and why the context is irrelevant, but if they're going to delete my technical response I wish they would delete the comment I'm responding to on my own question.

Answer (score 2):

The error is indeed confusing, I'm not sure what `TryFrom` implementation it's finding with `Infallible`... But there *is* a second error that you're just not showing us!

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<u8>: std::convert::From<&sqlite::Value>` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:2:25
    |
2   |     row.read::<Vec<u8>, _>(col).into()
    |                         ^ the trait `std::convert::From<&sqlite::Value>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `std::convert::From<T>`:
              <std::vec::Vec<u8> as std::convert::From<std::ffi::CString>>
              <std::vec::Vec<u8> as std::convert::From<std::string::String>>
              <std::vec::Vec<u8> as std::convert::From<&str>>
    = note: required for `&sqlite::Value` to implement `std::convert::Into<std::vec::Vec<u8>>`
    = note: required for `std::vec::Vec<u8>` to implement `std::convert::TryFrom<&sqlite::Value>`
note: required by a bound in `sqlite::Row::read`
   --> /home/mat/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/sqlite-0.31.1/src/cursor.rs:132:12
    |
130 |     pub fn read<'l, T, U>(&'l self, column: U) -> T
    |            ---- required by a bound in this associated function
131 |     where
132 |         T: TryFrom<&'l Value, Error = Error>,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Row::read`
```

The requirements on `Row.read` are that the target type has to implement `TryFrom<&Value>`. `Vec<u8>` does not implement that. It *does* implement `TryFrom<Value>`, but that's a different, weaker bound – you cannot construct a vec from just a reference to `Value`, you need an owned `Value`.

Because you only have a reference to `Row`, you need to extract a raw `&Value` first (with the indexer), then clone it, then turn it into a `Vec<u8>`.

```rust
pub fn read_vecu8( row: &sqlite::Row, col: &str ) -> Vec<u8> {
    row[col].clone().try_into().unwrap()
}
```

The supposed intention behind the API is that the authors didn't want to hide a full copy of the entire column value into a `Vec<u8>` behind the `read`, as that can potentially be very large.

If you don't need a full `Vec<u8>` and can live with a slice you can also do this, copy-free:

```rust
pub fn read_vecu8<'a>( row: &'a sqlite::Row, col: &str ) -> &'a [u8] {
    let val = &row[col];
    val.try_into().unwrap()
}
```

Comment: BTW if anyone knows what causes that first error, i.e. where the compiler is finding a candidate `TryFrom` with `Infallbile` please chime in. It would be potentially useful to file an issue to rust-lang to make the error message here more useful.

Comment: It's probably [this blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html#impl-TryFrom%3CU%3E-for-T) the compiler is trying to fit.

Comment: @V0ldek I still don't exactly understand what's happening here, could you explain more about the row. It seems to me like it has the `Vec<Value>` on it. And Value is an enum which has to own the Vec. Why can't you get the owned copy from the Row? This seems like a really awkward design choice for a row object -- it has to own the data and it won't give it up to you -- forcing you to copy it or slice it? Is there a reason you see why this design decision was made?

Comment: You have to remove or copy the `Value` if you're to hand out the owned `Value` I don't see how that's feasible given that `read` allows random access. Especially as your function and `read` both take a shared reference, not a mutable one.

Comment: I agree on this. There are two things, one, the API doesn't give you a way to consume a `Row` to get a `Value` for a column easily. You can `into` it into a `Vec<Value>` and then index manually, but you'd need to know the column-to-index mapping. Two, there is a known Rust limitation that there's no indexing trait that would allow you to move out a value. `Index` has to return a ref and `IndexMut` has to return a `mut` ref, there's no `OwnedIndex` or anything like that.

If this irks you you should probably propose a feature to the `sqlite` crate.

Comment: The `Row` has a reference to the column-index map and then a `Vec` of values: https://docs.rs/sqlite/latest/src/sqlite/cursor.rs.html#24-27 It could have a `get_col` function that just consumes the row and gives you a value of a single column... it just doesn't. But it could be a worthwile addition to the API.

Comment: @V0ldek or, more easily and consistent with Rust. It could make a newtype of `Option<>` called `MaybeRead<>` and make a `Row` of `Vec<MaybeRead<Value>>` and provide something that `std::mem::take()` from the MaybeRead and returns the owned type leaving None in its place. This would allow you to take from a Column with out consuming a row, and to subsequently take from multiple columns.

Comment: Upstream suggestion to fix problem: https://github.com/stainless-steel/sqlite/issues/76#issue-1928516690